# Adding a URL link to iOS app that is not optimized for mobile platforms (rejection possibility)

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I have been doing some research about iOS app approval process, but I can't seem to find one thing that is pretty important in my case.  I have added a simple url link to a website (I did not use a web view for the reason I am about to explain).

What I have found is that Apple specifies that font within the app should not be smaller than size 11.  They also say that the user should not have to zoom in.  Well, unfortunately I have a client who wants me to place a link of her website in a menu section of the app.  I told the client that I was concerned that there may be an issue since this website is not optimized for mobile devices.  Basically, this link shows a desktop version of a site on a mobile phone.

I have searched online for many guidelines, but I just haven't spotted anything yet.  I would guess that they would reject it, but I was just curious if anyone happened to know for sure or knew where I should look to find this out.

Thanks

Comment: If it's an external link it will open in Safari. What's the problem?

Comment: Yeah thats why I made it external.  So I'm assuming that based on your comment as long as I make it an external link then it won't be an issue in terms of approval?

Comment: They might say that you should use a Webview, but that happens rarely.